# Ruby/GEM install Middleman error: The 'fast_blank' native gem requires installed build tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, middleman

I'm trying to install https://middlemanapp.com/ using "gem", but getting the following error. I read the link in the error message, but I can't find any solution.

C:\Users\user1>ruby -v
    ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]

```
C:\Users\user1>gem -v
2.5.2

C:\Users\user1>gem install middleman
Fetching: bundler-1.13.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.13.6
Fetching: rack-2.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-2.0.1
Fetching: tilt-2.0.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tilt-2.0.5
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Fetching: fast_blank-1.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing middleman:
        The 'fast_blank' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions

at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Comment: hmmm... gotta ask. Do you have the dev kit installed?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the Ruby `DevKit` installed on your computer or you haven't proper edited the generated `config.yml` from Devkit installation.

You can download the Ruby `DevKit` from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads. Download the right one for your version of Ruby:

- Ruby 2.0.0 and above (32bits): mingw64-32-4.7.2
- Ruby 2.0.0 and above x64 (64bits): mingw64-64-4.7.2

After downloading, run it to extract it somewhere (permanent). Then, using the terminal, move to the folder where devkit in located: `cd DevKit`, then run in terminal:

`ruby dk.rb init`

Now you have to edit your `config.yml` file located in the `devkit` folder and add the absolute path to any installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the `DevKit`, that were not automagically discovered. Eg: `- C:/Ruby22-x64`

Finally, you must run the following instruction:

`ruby dk.rb install`

More info about **DevKit instalation** here: 
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit